# From .Net Core Web Application (MVC), WebAPI in Same solution returns 404

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

My first time using .net core

I was able to build a functioning webApi that calls data from my SQL server using Onion Layers.

```
Architecture
  Core
     Application Services
     Domain Services
  Core.Entity
Infrastructure
UI
  API
     CemeteryAPI
  Web
     MVC Web Application
```

If I set my UI.API.Cemetery as my Startup project, I can simply go to localHost:port/api/cemetery and I get my list from the DB.

If I set my Web / MVC Application as the startup, I get a 404 when I go to the same path...I've never done this before and I can't seem to find any articles that indicate what to expect.

I have Swagger running in the MVC Application and it also indicates no routes?

I'm not sure if I need to add additional routing beyond the MVC out of the box routing?  As this is my very first time using .core, I'm not sure whether I need to inject something or I'm totally in left field on my current build.

Comment: I think you should start both projects together. Cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2017

Comment: That did it.  I totally had no idea I could do that.  Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer was from the comment from Johey, to start multiple projects.